# Alert view with taking input password

Tags: swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

In the following code, it is successfully implemented. Just need one modification. When the app initially opens the admin password should take a default password "Hello" and then when the user has access to the admin password, will edited and save it and then it will be in the key "admin password"

How can I make that default password possible on the first?

```
func enableSectionAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Admin Password", message: "Please input admin password", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let enable = UIAlertAction(title: "Enable", style: .default) { (_) in
        let field = alertController.textFields?[0].text
            if let x = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "admin password"), x == field {

                self.demosSelectionEnabled()
                self.showSection.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                self.showSection.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
            }
            else{

                let wrongPwd = UIAlertController(title: "Wrong Admin Password", message: nil, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                wrongPwd.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                self.present(wrongPwd, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Admin Password"
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

    alertController.addAction(enable)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want the default password to be "Hello", and have the option to change this later, and persist in userDefaults.
If this is the case, why not initially set the default value as follows:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("Hello", forKey: "admin password")
```

Set it just once in maybe AppDelegate, using the following method:

```
private func setDefaultPassword() {
    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "admin password") == nil {
        UserDefaults.standard.set("Hello", forKey: "admin password")
    }
}
```

Comment: So I just put the following line of code in my AppDelegate and thats it? 
    UserDefaults.standard.set("Hico1234", forKey: "admin password")

Comment: Does the function setDefaultPassword need to be called from my enableSectionAlert, or once the app runs and if the admin password key is empty, it will take the input Hello?

Comment: I think just call it from appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions() in AppDelegate and that should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize a textfield with initial text this way

```
alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.text = "Hello"
    textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want that the password "Hello" allows the user to login after they installed the app. Once they are logged in they can change the password, right?

Do archive this check in the applicationDidLaunch method of your AppDelegate if a value for the key `admin password` is set. `UserDefaults.standard.string` returns `nil` if there is no value set for this key. If you get `nil` from this call just set the string to `Hello`.

This allows the user to login with `Hello` until the password save in the user defaults is changed.